# iPhone App - Using and Storing Contact Photos Best Practice

Tags: iphone, ios6

I was wondering if anyone had any best practices or advice for using contact photos in an app. Essentially I'm building an app that mimics the given contact app except my app will provide the contacts and their photos - this is so the user doesn't have to add contacts etc.

I can get my app to read an XML file for the contact information though I may change this to the JSON stuff served from a web server - right now the XML is within the app for testing purposes and I have to read up on JSON. This XML file simply holds the contact information and I show a contact photo that's in the support files for testing purposes too.

What would be a good way to server contact photos? Any best practices or advice? Should I store photos on the users phones and just reference them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi for that case use Lazyloading

checkout this [LazyloadingSample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/index.html)

Comment: Freaking awesome. I'll give it a read when I finish my app but that looks exactly lik what I need.

Comment: I can't. I don't have enough reputation yet.